# ensuring STOMP socket connection is established before subscribing

Tags: angular, websocket, stomp

In my Angular 2 project, I am using the [ng2-stomp-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-stomp-service) to establish a socket connection to the server.

Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes I get this error when trying to subscribe to the socket, saying that my connection has not been established yet:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet
    at SockJS.send (main.js:158)
    at Client._transmit (stomp.js:159)
    at Client.subscribe (stomp.js:379)
    at StompService.subscribe (stomp.service.ts:132)
    at slide-manager.service.ts:129
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3933)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:141)
    at zone.js:818
    at SockJS.send (main.js:158)
    at Client._transmit (stomp.js:159)
    at Client.subscribe (stomp.js:379)
    at StompService.subscribe (stomp.service.ts:132)
    at slide-manager.service.ts:129
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3933)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:141)
    at zone.js:818
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:770)
    at zone.js:821
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3924)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
    at WebSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:490)
```

The piece of this stack trace that belongs to me is the slide-manager.service.ts:129.  That code is at the stomp.subscribe line of this code:

```
this.socketConfig = {
      host: 'http://' + getHost() + '/app-ws',
      debug: true,
      queue: {'init': false}
    };   

 this.stomp.configure(this.socketConfig);
 this.stomp.startConnect().then((frame) => {
 this.stomp.done('init');
 this.connected = true;
 this.spectraSubscription = this.stomp.subscribe('/topic/spectra', (spectra) => {
     if (spectra && (!this.theChart || hostElement.childElementCount === 0) && !this.refreshFlag) {
         this.makeChart(spectra.points, hostElement);
         this.refreshFlag = true;
     } else if (spectra && (this.theChart || hostElement.childElementCount > 0) || this.refreshFlag) {
         this.theChart.collectionView.sourceCollection = spectra.points;
         this.theChart.collectionView.refresh();
     }
  });
```

How can I ensure that the connection is indeed established before it tries to execute the .subscribe()?  I figured putting it in the .then() block would do the trick, since that should only be executed after the connection's promise has resolved, but apparently it's still getting triggered even when no connection exists (according to the error).

Or is there more at play here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by checking the built-in "status" property of the stomp client:

```
if (this.stomp.status === 'CONNECTED') {
    // do stuff that requires a connection, like establish subscriptions
}
```

Comment: What if connection does not exist? Do you just ignore the required actions that need to take place?

Comment: To be honest, since this was 3 years ago, I really don't remember how the program handled that scenario.  I imagine it wouldn't come as 'CONNECTED' so we'd either have to wait or try to re-establish the connection.  Perhaps in an ELSE statement.  Sorry I don't have more detail, as I can no longer access this code.

Answer (score 0):

For folks using the stompjs library, there's a potential solution:

For certain use cases, you might want to hold off until the connection is established and only then continue. You can use something like this

```js
import { Client } from "@stomp/stompjs";

const client = new Client();
// client config...

const awaitConnect = async (awaitConnectConfig) => {
    const {
      retries = 3,
      curr = 0,
      timeinterval = 100,
    } = awaitConnectConfig || {};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(timeinterval);
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (client.connected) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          console.log("failed to connect! retrying");
          if (curr >= retries) {
            console.log("failed to connect within the specified time interval");
            reject();
          }
          this.awaitConnect({ ...awaitConnectConfig, curr: curr + 1 });
        }
      }, timeinterval);
    });
  };
```

And then call it

```
await awaitConnect()
```

This will block the main thread until the underlying web socket connection is established, and will check every `timeinterval` ms for the status till the `retries` are exhausted